# Limit a process's CPU and memory usage, with Docker perhaps?

Tags: linux, docker

Are there anyways to run a process inside a Docker container without building the container plus all the other isolations (IO, etc)?

My end goal is not to build an isolated environment, but rather limit CPU and Memory usage (ability to malloc). And using VM instances is just a too bit overhead. The ulimit, systemd, cpulimit, and other Linux tools doesn't seem to provide a good solution here. For example it seems that systemd only kills the process if RES/VIRT exceeds threshold.

Docker seems to do the trick without performance degradation, but are there any simple methods to run e.g. a python script without all the extra hassle and configurations?

Or are there any other ways to limit CPU and Mem usage?

Comment: Configure a container once manually and make some bash script to automate launch of the container and deployment of a custom script from your file system? Though it'll probably be annoyingly slow if you frequently restart the container

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question; the Stack Overflow [help/on-topic] describes what's on-topic here.  I might start by looking at questions like [Prevent a process from using too much CPU even if available](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427018/prevent-a-process-from-using-too-much-cpu-even-if-available) on Unix & Linux SE, and ask there if that set of tools doesn't work for you.